# Handle exceptions while iterating over a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

I'm searching over a text to extract some data, I need to handle the case when I  find nothing:

```
items = {'item_1':['----']*len(some_text),
         'item_2':['----']*len(some_text),
         'item_3':['----']*len(some_text)]

for i, data in enumerate(some_text):
    try:
        items['item_1'][i] = re.findall('regex_1',data)[0]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
    try:
        items['item_2'][i] = re.findall('regex_2',data)[0]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
    try:
        items['item_3'][i] = re.findall('regex_2',data)[0]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
```

I'm doing it that way and not this:

```
for i, data in enumerate(some_text):
    try:
        items['item_1'][i] = re.findall('regex_1',data)[0]
        items['item_2'][i] = re.findall('regex_2',data)[0]
        items['item_3'][i] = re.findall('regex_2',data)[0]
    except (IndexError):
        pass
```

Because in the last case I will lose all the data if only one of the search fails, but I'm repeating a lot of code.

Edit.

My expectect result is to have a dictonary with most of the items.

For example if:

item_1  is an address
 item_2 is a name
 item_3 is a calification

If and exception occurs while searching address, I still want to be able to get the name and the calification. I also wan  t to handle the exception so I can put a message like 'not found' if needed

Comment: Why is there no `regex_3`?

Comment: Don't you want it to fail if any of the searches fail, or is there a reason that you want to still capture whatever data that you can?

Comment: So what's your question, in the first place? Probably you should explain what the expected result should look like if any of the searches fails, because in either version of the code, the respective list will not be appended to, and the next iteration will produce an `IndexError`.

Comment: I think OP wants to ignore any `IndexError` and continue execution of the code as though no exception was thrown.

Comment: But then he needs to specify how to construct a list that doesn't have all elements. Either he needs to insert an empty match of some sort, or he ends up with lists of unforeseeable length, in which case he cannot simply assign to `[i]` but would need to `append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to avoid repeating your code is to use a loop. First, package up your pairs of dictionary keys and regexes into something iterable, then loop over the pairs. Here's what that might look like using a dictionary for the keys and regexes (but a list of 2-tuples would work fine too):

```
key_regex_dict = {'item_1': 'regex_1', 'item_2': 'regex_2', 'item_3': 'regex_3'}
for i, data in enumerate(some_text):
    for key, regex in key_regex_dict.items():
        try:
            items[key][i] = re.findall(regex, data)[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
```